# realizar un trigger tipo update

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo la siguiente consulta:
Realize un trigger de tipo update en la tabla "x" y verifique si los datos nuevos del nombre y apelido ya existen, si existen no modifiquen, de lo contrario modifique la informacion.

```
create trigger ActualizarInfo
on tabla1
for update
as
  begin 
       declare @nombre varchar(30)
               @apellido varchar (30)

     if exists (name=@nombre and lastname=@apellido)
        print 'usuario existente, no modificar'

   end
   else 
      begin
           update tabla1
           set name=@nombre
           set lastname=@apellido

end
```

mi duda es: si puedo manejar asi mis variables que declare (@nombre,@apellido)?
o como valido si exiten o no ?

Comment: Hola @m3nt0r1337, creo que vendría bien que mostraras cuál es la llave primaria de la tabla y que aclares un poco el tema, ya que por ahora es ambiguo (y por tanto sujeto a interpretación). Si lo que buscas es evitar que se pueda duplicar la información de nombre y apellido, te recomiendo también evaluar la posibilidad de utilizar un constraint **unique**, que sirve para ese propósito y será, en general, más eficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo, lo que necesitas es un `INSTEAD OF` trigger, porque debes revisar los cambios **antes** que se modifiquen los datos, no después. Y luego deberías entender cómo funcionan los triggers en SQL Server.

Siempre hay que pensar que cuando realizas un `INSERT`, `UPDATE` o `DELETE`, debes pensar en que vas a modificar un *set* de datos, y no sólo una única fila (aún cuando la operación en particular sea una sola fila, debes asumir que pueden modificarse más de una a la vez). Es por esto que la solución no puede ser asignando datos a simples variables, porque eso asume que siempre se afectó una única fila.

Además, en un trigger puedes usar las seudo-tablas `INSERTED` y `DELETED`, que tienen todas las filas que fueron afectadas por tu operación. Es con estas tablas con las cuales debes comparar la información:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ActualizarInfo]
   ON  [dbo].[Tabla1]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
    SET A.Name      = ISNULL(A.Name,B.Name),
        A.LastName  = ISNULL(A.LastName,B.LastName)
    FROM dbo.Tabla1 A
    INNER JOIN INSERTED B
        ON A.ColumnaLlave = B.ColumnaLlave
    WHERE A.Name IS NULL
    OR A.LastName IS NULL;

END
```

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, voy a checar lo de las pseudo-tablas