# TRIGGER UPDATE para actualizar campo

Tags: sql-server

Tengo varias dudas de como crear un `trigger` para este `update` que tengo:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
    SET IBAN = LEFT(IBAN,16) + '****' + RIGHT(IBAN,14)
WHERE IBAN <>''
```

Necesito que tanto al crear (el cliente) como al modificar en campo (`IBAN`) ejecute el `trigger` con este `update`, agradezco que alguien me oriente un poco, con las pruebas que hice no obtuve ningún resultado.

Cosas del copia / pega que a veces no copia no pega, esto es con lo que estoy probando

- un error ya lo subsané y ya funciona, en vez de ON tenía OM.

  CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_ASTERISCOS
  ON  dbo.E07Clientes
  AFTER UPDATE
  AS
  BEGIN
  UPDATE E07Clientes
  SET IBAN = LEFT(IBAN,16) + '****' + RIGHT(IBAN,14)
  WHERE IBAN <>''
  END
  GO

y también tengo:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER INTER_ASTERISCOS
ON  [dbo].[E07Clientes]
  AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE E07Clientes
    SET IBAN = LEFT(IBAN,16) + '****' + RIGHT(IBAN,14)
    WHERE IBAN <>''
END
GO
```

Pero al actualizar desde el programa "no tengo acceso al mismo" si se añade un cliente nuevo pone los asteriscos en todos no solo en el cliente nuevo.
Si se intenta modificar el IBAN da el siguiente error ( OJO en el programa, en sql no me da ningún error)

Este es el error que sale en el programa:

[FireDac][DApt]-400. Update command updated [5] intead of [1] record. Posible reasons: update table does not have PK or row identifier, record has been changed/deleted by another user

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Espero que [este ejemplo de tigger](https://pixy.org/download/1562515/) te sirva. En caso de que no sea así, por favor muestra lo que has intentado. Me parece que lo que intentas hacer puede ser problemático.

Comment: Buenos días, muy bueno, el problema del copia / pega y las prisas, que a veces no se copia todo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estás modificando todos los registros de la tabla y esa no es la manera adecuada. Tienes que restringir los mismos a los que se están insertando o actualizando.

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.INTER_ASTERISCOS
ON  [dbo].[E07Clientes]
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE E07Clientes FROM E07CLIENTES 
        INNER JOIN inserted ON EO7CLIENTES.ID = inserted.ID 
            SET IBAN = LEFT(IBAN,16) + '****' + RIGHT(IBAN,14)
        WHERE IBAN <>''
            AND IBAN IS NOT NULL;
END
```

La parte más importante, como habrás observado es que la update se realiza contra la tabla, pero haciendo un inner join con la `pseudo-tabla inserted`, que es la que contiene los registros que se están insertando o actualizando. En la `pseudo-tabla deleted`, no mencionada en este código, en el trigger de update, dispondrías de los valores que tenían los registros justo antes de su modificación o borrado.

Además, solo se realiza si `IBAN` tiene algo.

Y también se realiza en el mismo trigger, para `insert` y `update`

Adicionalmente, esta labor la puedes realizar en los triggers `instead of` que se desencadenan antes de la inserción del registro y eres tú el encargado de realizar esta inserción o no.

En esta otra respuesta, tienes otro ejemplo con Instead of

[Trigger After instead of](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20186/realizar-un-trigger-tipo-update?rq=1)

Comment: Muchas gracias, el trigger que me pones me da un error (cerca de from) así que miré en la otra posibilidad con Instead of, y con este código en cliente nuevo va perfecto y no modifica ninguno existente, pero en los que quiero modificar no me hace nada ( normal no se donde poner esa parte)

Comment: ¿Cual es la primary key de la Tabla?. Ese inserted.id = EO7CLIENTES.ID tienes que cambiar ambos ids, por la columna identificativa de la tabla

Comment: Este es el código:

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ActualizarIBAN]
   ON  [dbo].[E07Clientes]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE A
    SET A.IBAN = LEFT(B.IBAN,16) + '****' + RIGHT(B.IBAN,14) /*SET A.IBAN      = ISNULL(A.IBAN,B.IBAN)*/

    FROM dbo.E07Clientes A
    INNER JOIN INSERTED B
        ON A.Id = B.Id
    WHERE A.IBAN<>'' AND A.IBAN IS NOT NULL;
END

Comment: La definición de la tabla, es lo importante. no el código del trigger. Si observas detenidamente el código, lo que hace es enlazar la tabla que tiene x millones de registros con la pseudoTabla inserted que tiene solo, los que se están actualizando/insertando cuando se ejecuta el trigger. Por una columna se enlazan o por dos o por.... Lo suyo es la columna Primary Key de la tabla `e07Clientes`

Comment: Aquí lo tienes mucho más detallado [trigger After insert](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/?s=trigger+after+insert)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo tengo